# How to run RScript using crontab in Mac OSX

Tags: r, macos, cron

I have searched around on how to do this on here and none have really solved my problem. Partially because i do not understand what is going on....unfortunately

I have an Rscript I am trying to schedule to run every day called: `JASON.r`

the code inside the script is the following:

```
setwd("/Volumes/3TB/")
install.packages("quantmod");library("quantmod")
getSymbols("AAPL")
write.csv(AAPL,"/Volumes/3TB/AAPL.csv")
quit(save='no')
```

I have found [THIS PAGE](https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2013/09/11/schedule-rscript-with-cron/) on how to do so, but i have been not been successful.
What I do is open terminal and type:

`Jason-Guevaras-iMac:~ rimeallthetime$ sudo crontab -e`

for which it returns the following:

```
crontab: no crontab for root - using an empty one

~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/tmp/crontab.fwiSAwWI4R" 0L, 0C
```

So then I came across [THIS POST](https://superuser.com/questions/201172/mac-crontab-is-never-created) which had similar issues and when I type:

```
Jason-Guevaras-iMac:~ rimeallthetime$ sudo su -
Jason-Guevaras-iMac:~ root# crontab -u rimeallthetime -e
crontab: no crontab for rimeallthetime - using an empty one

~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
"/tmp/crontab.L1nPwJdBRi" 0L, 0C
```

That is where I am at currently....

I have MAC OSX El Capitan version 10.11.4

Answer (score 2):

In Terminal, open the crontab with:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Press <kbd>i</kbd> to go into insert mode.

Add the following line:

```
0 */23 * * * Rscript /path/to/file/JASON.r
```

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode.

Type <kbd>ZZ</kbd>

You should see the following message: `crontab: installing new crontab`.

You can verify the crontab file by using `crontab -l`.

**Misc:**

This will run the file every 23 hours.

Each star/position corresponds to:

```
MIN HOUR DOM MON DOW CMD
```

Feel free to change it to suite your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i get the following error: `crontab: installing new crontab
"/tmp/crontab.bMC06Mo8eN":1: bad hour
crontab: errors in crontab file, can't install
Do you want to retry the same edit? `

Comment: I changed the the time and it seemed to work: `23 02 * * * Rscript /Volumes/3TB/JASON.R` but It did not create any output, as the rscript is suppose to create a `.csv` file

Comment: correct, that was my local time, but does that mean it will start the following day? I changed it to 2:30am to test if it will run

Comment: you should specify the file path to the file as well... e.g. `/Users/whoyouare/Documents/JASON.r` in the cronjob

Comment: on crontab? I specified the output file on the rscript.. @Coatless

Answer (score 2):

It might be worth mentioning that `cron` is still supported by OSX but [it has been deprecated in favor](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) of `launchd`.

To create a launchd job, you need to create a "plist" file giving all needed information to run the script and place it in folder `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. Here's an example plist file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>jason</string>
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
                <string>Rscript /path/to/JASON.R</string>
        </array>
        <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
        <dict>
                <key>Minute</key>
                     <integer>0</integer>
                <key>Hour</key>
                     <integer>23</integer>
        </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then you need to load this plist file into the launchd scheduler and start it:

```
 launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/jason.plist
 launchctl start jason
```

In the second line the name `jason` corresponds to the field `Label` in the plist file.